# Is quod too ambiguous for "that which"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, conjugation

I'm trying to write a variation of Ovid's phrase "*Omnia mutantur, nihil interit*" — "Everything changes, nothing perishes". So far I've came up with "***quod mutat, non pereat***" — "that which changes, shall not perish".

After translating from several languages the construct "that which [does x]" I get something like "*quod* x", conforming with phrases like "*Non omne quod nitet* (shines) *aurum est*". However when translating it back to English we get "the x" (eg "*quod mutat*" -> "that/the changes").

So I can't tell whether or not I should worry about this since automatic translation from Latin to English is pretty bad at times plus it seems that *quod* can be used in many different ways.
I believe I've picked the right [conjugation for *muto*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muto#Conjugation) but if that is not the case this could be the source of confusion for the translation engines so I'm asking for help to check if my logic follows.

Comment: Do not use Google Translator or other automatic translation software for Latin translation. They are all terrible.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Got it, thanks! May I use the phrase I wrote with peace of mind you think?

Comment: What you have now is good, but it translates to: "Let that which changes not perish." It's a little less matter-of-fact than your original English, but it's good Latin still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Quod* is definitely a correct and idiomatic way to express rules that would be rendered with “that which ⋯” in English. As you have found out, machine translators for Latin are useless. But open any anthology of Latin proverbs and quotations at the letter Q, and you will find examples like:

> *Quod nocet, docet.* (That which hurts, teaches.)
> *Quod licet Jovi, non licet bovi.* (What Jupiter may do, an ox may not do.)
> *Quod non est in actis, non est in mundo.* (What is not on paper [in a court case], is not in the world.)

And even more if you also look for other forms of the relative pronoun:

> *Qui tacet, consentire videtur.* (He who is silent appears to agree.)
> *Quem di diligunt, adolescens moritur.* (Plautus, Bacchides, 4,7,18: He whom the gods love dies young.)

There is also the possibility to say *quidquid* (whatever, whatsoever), e.g.:

> *Quidquid sub terra est, in apricum proferet aetas.* (Horace Ep. 1; 6, 24: Whatever is underground, time will bring it forth into the sunlight.)
> *Quidquid latet, apparebit.* (Dies Irae echoing the same thought: All that is hidden will come out.)
> *Quidquid agis, prudenter agas et respice finem.* (Whatever you do, act wisely and think of the end.)

Like “whatever” in English, this stresses that the rule applies to any candidate without exceptions.